# X2go Black Screen

Tags: x2go

I've installed x2go for testing remote desktop. When I connect to my server (which is running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, with Unity as the desktop environment) I get a black screen. In the settings, I did choose to use Unity as the desktop environment, and I've tried a bunch of the other choices, but it just gives a black screen. I'm not sure how to troubleshoot it?

Comment: Do you get any error messages in `sudo dmesg --follow` on the server?

Answer (score 1):

x2go unfortunately does not actually support the unity3d desktop environment.  It does support the Unity 2d desktop environment, but that is deprecated as of 12.04.  So, sorry, you can't get Unity running through x2go as things stand.  Theoretically you could get compiz running on Mate, but I've never had a lot of success with that through x2go.

Edit:

Something I have tried and sort of gotten working recently is LXDE with a compistor on top...  It's kind of buggy, but it does work to some extent.