# X2Go Client Black Screen connecting to Ubuntu using Session Type Connect to local desktop

Tags: server, remote-desktop, x11-forwarding, x2go, x2goclient

I've been using X2Go for a while now to connect from Windows10 to remote Ubuntu server.

I've been using the X2Go Session Type "Connect to local desktop".

Everything was working last night.  Today when I tried connecting the X2Go Client seems to connect.  However, where the X2Go Client GUI normally displays the Ubuntu desktop, I get a black screen which temporarily shows X2Go logo/name.

There are quite a few pages related to X2Go Black Screen, but I couldn't find an answer to my problem.
Here are a few I looked:
[x2go do not connect to active desktop session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1169057/x2go-do-not-connect-to-active-desktop-session)
[X2go Black Screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/739236/x2go-black-screen)

While ssh'd into remote machine using putty simultaneously while X2Go client is connected and showing black screen, if I run x2golistdesktops from terminal, I see

```
theusername@:50
theusername@:1
```

I think the theusername@:50 is the X2Go connection.  This concerns me b/c in info reported by X2Go client (see below) I see `Info: Forwarding X11 connections to display 'localhost:0'.`

I've tried restarted my local machine.  I've also restarted the X2Go service on the remote Ubuntu machine.  I was also able to connect to remote machine using putty with x11 forwarding and xming and get GUI (e.g. for emacs).

Here is info reported by X2Go:

Copyright (C) 2001, 2010 NoMachine.

See http://www.nomachine.com/ for more information.

Info: Proxy running in client mode with pid '7496'.

Session: Starting session at 'Fri Nov 13 11:28:10 2020'.

Info: Connecting to remote host 'localhost:58746'.

Info: Connection to remote proxy 'localhost:58746' established.

Info: Connection with remote proxy completed.

Warning: Unrecognized session type 'unix-kde-depth_32'. Assuming agent session.

Warning: Failed to read data from the X auth command.

Warning: Generated a fake cookie for X authentication.

Info: Using ADSL link parameters 512/24/1/0.

Info: Using cache parameters 4/4096KB/8192KB/8192KB.

Info: Using pack method '16m-jpeg-9' with session 'unix-kde-depth_32'.

Info: Using ZLIB data compression 1/1/32.

Info: Using ZLIB stream compression 4/4.

Info: No suitable cache file found.

Info: Forwarding X11 connections to display 'localhost:0'.

Session: Session started at 'Fri Nov 13 11:28:12 2020'.

Info: Established X server connection.

Info: Using shared memory parameters 0/0K.